# How to be able to (from code) override window title in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-in

I've written an add-in that we've used for vs 2005, 2008 and 2010 where I set the title based on some environment information (and other things). I'm basically intercepting the WM_SETTEXT msg through SetWindowsHookEx and is using SetWindowText on both the "main window" (that fixes the text when alt-tabbing or hovering over the task bar) and the "editor window" that is using the class name "IDEOwner" (this fixes the title of the actual visual studio window)

However in vs 2012 there is no "IDEOwner" which means that this way can't be used to set the title of the "editor window" (the "main window" still works.

If anyone know how I can access and override this editor window title I would be very happy.

Thanks,

Henrik